# How to set .addSnapShotListener to Collection reference in fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In My Application i want to add a loading layout before the data gets fetched from the Firestore.

So I tried adding Snapsnot listener but it doesn't worked well.

I want to know how can i do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use `addSnapshotListener`, try the following:

```
final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
            return;
        }

        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current data: " + snapshot.getData());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null");
        }
    }
});
```

The `document()` returns a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference), and the class `DocumentReference` contains the method `addSnapshotListener`

Comment: Actually I'm not referring to any documents I'm just refering to a collection and that returns the data from all the documents..!!

Comment: Sorry for replying late..!!

Comment: If you using `collection() ` then use `get()` to retrieve the data and then use addOnCompleteListener

Comment: @CodeREDInnovations Since the answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as correct thank you!

Comment: Actually what I'm really try to get is...!! When the user opens my application I wanted to show a loading animation (shimmer effect) to the user's before the data fetches from the server. I did that properly when I used firebase database but now I switched to cloud firestore I'm not well with the things in the firestore. So I can with this .addsnapshotlistener and wanted to know how can I use that to show the loading effect before fetching